# Expectation of product of dependent random variables with partial information

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$  are identical but not independent.  $E[X_1 X_2]$,$E[X_2 X_3]$, $E[X_1 X_3]$  are known. Is it possible to approximate or bound  $E[X_1 X_2 X_3]$.

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Comment: I assume random variables are positively correlated. (At least to simlify the problem) Then, we have $E[X_1X_2]  > E[X_1] E[X_2]$; and $E[X_1 X_2 X_3] > E[X_1X_2] E[X_3]$ ( for all three pairwise combinations) If this relationship is valid. More specific question is that is it possible to bound aggregate correlation when pairwise correlation is known?

Comment: What is their distribution?

Comment: You asked to find a bound in terms of $E(X_iX_j)$ for every $i\ne j$ and you accepted an answer using $E(|X_i|^3)$. How so?

Comment: The bound  can be derived in terms of known values $E[X_i]$ and/or $E[X_i X_j]$

Comment: This problem was a part of research I am dealing with. In my case $X_{i}$ values are assigned to random points in two dimensional space. Overall distribution of $X_{i}$ is very close to gamma distribution. This way, I know the moments of $E[X_{i}]$. On the other hand, if two points fall within certain distance their assigned values are correlated. Maybe I need to update the question and  add that approximate distribution of $X_{i}$ is known.

Comment: "The bound can be derived in terms of known values E[Xi] and/or E[XiXj]" This assertion happens to be frankly wrong in general since there is no way to deduce the former from the latter. If indeed you meant to restrict the setting to some known distribution, this should have been mentioned in the question and I fail to understand why you left unanswered the comment "What is their distribution?" (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can imagine is the Hölder’s inequality $$|\mathbb{E}[XY]|\le\mathbb{E}[|XY|]\le(\mathbb{E}|X|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\mathbb{E}|Y|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ where $p$ and $q$ satisfy$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$$ You may easily extend it to three RVs by assuming $X_1X_2=X$, $X_3=Y$, $p=\frac{2}{3}$, and $q=\frac{1}{3}$ and then do it again for $X_1X_2$ to get

$$|\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2X_3]|\le\mathbb{E}[|X_1X_2X_3|]\le\sqrt[3]{\mathbb{E}|X_1|^3\mathbb{E}|X_2|^3\mathbb{E}|X_3|^3}$$